# How to directly access a different language on site.com

Tags: site.com, translation, language

I have a problem with the ?language parameter on site.com. For some reason I can't access the site directly with the parameter in the URL.

For instance: http://example.com/subpage?language=uk_GB will show 404 page, however if I use a language drop down field to switch the language I see the UK page correctly.

This issue preventing me from sharing links of international/translated pages with others.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The language for UK English should be passed as en_GB, not uk_GB as it is a combination of the Language Code and Country Code (see below screen capture).  When it is set to that it should work fine with the language parameter; however, if uk_GB it should default back to the Site.com default.
[image: Site.com Language Setting].

It could be that there is some other custom logic (e.g., JavaScript) executing that dynamically tries to redirect or do something else based on the param and is not finding it, resulting in the 404.